# Why is numpy.vectorize() changing the division output of a scalar function?

Tags: python, numpy, division

I'm obtaining a strange result when I vectorise a function with numpy.

```
import numpy as np
def scalar_function(x, y):
    """ A function that returns x*y if x<y and x/y otherwise
    """
    if x < y :
        out = x * y 
    else:
        out = x/y 
    return out

def vector_function(x, y):
    """
    Make it possible to accept vectors as input
    """
    v_scalar_function = np.vectorize(scalar_function)
    return v_scalar_function(x, y)
```

we do have

```
scalar_function(4,3)
# 1.3333333333333333
```

Why is the vectorized version giving this strange output?

```
vector_function(np.array([3,4]), np.array([4,3]))
[12  1]
```

While this call to the vectorized version works fine:

```
vector_function(np.array([4,4]), np.array([4,3]))
[1.         1.33333333]
```

Reading [numpy.divide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html):

> Notes
>   The floor division operator // was added in Python 2.2 making // and / equivalent operators. The default floor division operation of / can be replaced by true division with from `__future__` import division.
>   In Python 3.0, // is the floor division operator and / the true division operator. The true_divide(x1, x2) function is equivalent to true division in Python.

Makes me think this might be a remaining issue related to python2? 
But I'm using python 3!

Comment: The docs say "The output type is determined by evaluating the first element of the input, unless it is specified". My guess is that multiplication of integer types in the first instance is automatically cast to `int` type for the whole return array, while division, even resulting from 4/4 is automatically upcasted to float

Comment: As an aside; I see you're primarily used to R. Just checking you're aware that `vectorize` is a convenience function that adds no speed over a python `for` loop and should be avoided whenever possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs for [`numpy.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) state:

> The output type is determined by evaluating the first element of the
>   input, unless it is specified

Since you did not specify a return data type, and the first example is integer multiplication, the first array is also of integer type and rounds the values. Conversely, when the first operation is division, the datatype is automatically upcasted to float. You can fix your code by specifying a dtype in `vector_function` (which doesn't necessarily have to be as big as 64-bit for this problem):

```
def vector_function(x, y):
    """
    Make it possible to accept vectors as input
    """
    v_scalar_function = np.vectorize(scalar_function, otypes=[np.float64])
    return v_scalar_function(x, y)
```

Separately, you should also make note from that very same documentation that `numpy.vectorize` is a convenience function and basically just wraps a Python `for` loop so is not vectorized in the sense that it provides any real performance gains.

For a binary choice like this, a better overall approach would be:

```
def vectorized_scalar_function(arr_1, arr_2):
    return np.where(arr_1 < arr_2, arr_1 * arr_2, arr_1 / arr_2)

print(vectorized_scalar_function(np.array([4,4]), np.array([4,3])))
print(vectorized_scalar_function(np.array([3,4]), np.array([4,3])))
```

The above should be orders of magnitude faster and (possibly coincidentally rather than a hard-and-fast rule to rely on) doesn't suffer the type casting issue for the result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the suggestion to use `np.where`. This is similar to the R function [ifelse](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse). You write that the output of `np.where` doesn't suffer from the type casting issue, but that it is "possibly coincidentally" and not a "rule to rely on". Any insight, place where the rule for the type output of np.where would be specified?

Comment: @PaulRougieux the vast majority of methods allow you to specify the `dtype` of the output. As for casting rules in general, if left to numpy, that's more tricky. I remember that there used to be a table of precedence but I'm not sure that exists / is still relevant. The one big issue that bit me a few times is that an int array, if left to default, will be 32 bit on Windows and can silently overflow on things like `sum`

Answer (score 2):

Checking which statemets are triggered:

```
import numpy as np

def scalar_function(x, y):
    """ A function that returns x*y if x<y and x/y otherwise
    """
    if x < y :
        print('if x: ',x)
        print('if y: ',y)
        out = x * y 
        print('if out', out)
    else:
        print('else x: ',x)
        print('else y: ',y)
        out = x/y
        print('else out', out)

    return out

def vector_function(x, y):
    """
    Make it possible to accept vectors as input
    """
    v_scalar_function = np.vectorize(scalar_function)
    return v_scalar_function(x, y)


vector_function(np.array([3,4]), np.array([4,3]))

if x:  3
if y:  4
if out 12
if x:  3
if y:  4
if out 12
else x:  4
else y:  3
else out 1.3333333333333333 # <-- seems that the value is calculated correctly, but the wrong dtype is returned
```

So, you can rewrite the scalar function:

```
def scalar_function(x, y):
    """ A function that returns x*y if x<y and x/y otherwise
    """
    if x < y :
        out = x * y 
    else:
        out = x/y
    return float(out)


vector_function(np.array([3,4]), np.array([4,3]))
array([12.        ,  1.33333333])
```